If $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A-\bigcup_{j=1}^{n} A_j)=0$
I'm trying to solve a measure theory problem. Here $\mu $ is a finite pre-measure in an algebra.
To continue with the resolution, I opened the hypothesis that the following is true:
If $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu(A-\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_{j})=0$
By doing this, I managed to solve the exercise. The problem is that even though the hypothesis seemed to be true, I cannot prove its veracity. Could anyone help me with this please?

Hint: $\bigcup_{1\leq j \leq n+1} A_j\setminus \bigcup_{1\leq j \leq n} A_j, n\ge 1$ is a  disjoint sequence.

I could finally prove it:
Put $B_n=A-A_n$ $(n=1,2,3,...)$
Now, due to the continuity from above and finitude of $\mu$, we have the following:
$A-\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}=\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}B_{j}\searrow \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}B_{j}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}= A- \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n} \implies \lim_{\rightarrow \infty} \mu (A-\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}) = \mu (A- \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n})=\mu (\varnothing) =0 $
